What is the correct quoting for a variable expansion (a filename) inside double-quoted backticks in CSH?
Let's say that you're in a system with devilish filenames, for eg.
# a horrible filename: 
set link = '  '\''  "  \  `  $#  \
\
'
# an even worse logical link
ln -s $link:q $link:q

Now I would like to read the target of that logical link and put it in the target variable, so that echo $target:q would output:
  '  "  \  `  $#  



Here's what I've tried:
$ set target = `readlink -n $lnk:q`
$ echo $target:q
' " \ ` $#
$ set target = "`readlink -n $lnk:q`"
Unmatched '.
$ set target = "`readlink -n "$lnk"`"
Unmatched `.
$ set target = "`readlink -n '$lnk:q'`"
Unmatched ".

What is the correct syntax for using a variable within double-quoted back-ticks?

It's not clear (to me) if you want literal back-tic characters in your filename, or if you need the cmd-substitution provided by back-tics. Please edit your quesztion to clarify this and I will delete this comment. Good luck.

I'm referring to the last line of your example # a harmful filename:               -> to  "  \'`

@shelter in bash it would be lnk=\'$'to\nto  "  `' . In my example lnk is supposed to represent an arbitrary filename, so it can contain anything. I'm updating an old csh script that doesn't care about word-splitting/glob-expansion/etc when expanding variables, which should be fine for most of a script but not when dealing with the user-provided filenames.


Arg, still unclear to me. Now you have added a $ char compared to you csh assignment to lnk.. So are all chars in lnk=\'$'to\nto  "  \'meant to be literal chars that should not be processed as csh meta-chars?  2)While a interesting "how many angels can dance on the head of a ping" sort-of-question, (for an ancient csh user like myself, (they made me do it!) ). I think this is really proving to you that shell scripting has its limits. Andcsh` is the first in the list of limited shells. I'll keep messing with this for a bit, but I think you're right. Not possible. Good luck!



Or you'll need to come up with a way to incorporate a filter that adds an extra level of escaping to $lnk to get around the syntax issues created by using command-substitution. To prove this to yourself, you could type in the variable values inside the back-quotes (rather than use the variable). then manually escape charactres to get that to work. If you can get it to work, then you can think about what you will have to do with csh and other filters to make those changes to the temporary presentation of the $Lnk:q variable. Good luck again! (-;!


Let's start with an extract of the CSH manual:

Command Substitution
A command enclosed by backquotes (`...`) is performed by a subshell. Its standard output is broken into separate words at each space character, tab and newline; null words are discarded. This text replaces the backquoted string on the current command line.
Within double-quotes, only newline characters force new words; space and tab characters are preserved. However, a final newline is ignored. It is therefore possible for a command substitution to yield a partial word.

So, getting a path directly from a command substitution would, at the very least, require to enclose the backticks within double-quotes. That'll work as long as the path doesn't contain any LF character (which is a very common case ;-P). The newlines will split the result into different words, successive newlines will be squeezed, and the trailing newlines will be discarded.

1. The correct way to use a variable within a double-quoted command substitution.
With "`readlink $link:q`", CSH expands $link:q before launching the sub-shell, which will lead to potentially broken commands being executed. To safeguard against it you'll need to make $link:q a literal string until the sub-shell is executed; you can do it by closing the double-quotes, escaping the $ and then re-opening the double-quotes; for example:
set target = "`   readlink "\$"link:q   `"

echo $target:q

A somewhat more readable way:
set target = "`"'   readlink -n $link:q   '"`"

echo $target:q

Outputs:
  '  "  \  `  $#  

It's a good start, as readlink seems to output the correct value, and the blanks were preserved; but as you can see, the LFs disappeared...
2. How to get the path outputted by readlink, verbatim.
Here comes the difficult part. I've been exploring quite a few possibilities and, given the limitations of CSH's command substitutions, the only robust solution I could find is to generate a csh script that defines the value of the target variable, then source it:
( readlink -n $link:q && echo ) | \
sed -e "    s/\\/\\\\/g"          \
    -e '    s/\!/\\\!/g'          \
    -e "    s/'/'\\''/g"          \
    -e "1   s/^/set target = '/"  \
    -e '$ ! s/$/\\/'              \
    -e '$   s/$/'"'/"             \
> target_def.csh

source target_def.csh

echo $target:q

note: the escaping logic relies on the trailing LF that readlink adds to the output
fixed: on macOS readlink doesn't add a trailing LF when the path of the target already ends with one... A workaround is to use readlink -n and append the trailing LF oneself
fixed: CSH escaping isn't so simple; there are other characters like \ and ! that need to be escaped, even within
single-quotes.
Output:
  '  "  \  `  $#  




APENDUM
Now that I've learned more about CSH, I'm not sure that I got my CSH escaping right; I fixed a few special cases in the previous code but there might be others that I'm not aware of...
So, at the end of the day, it may be safer to make use of the :h modifier instead. The idea is to add a / at the end of each line and append an additional not(/) to the last line of the output; you will then be able to rebuild the original output by replacing the trailing / characters with a LF and stripping the trailing /* of the last line:
set target

foreach line ("`"' (readlink -n $link:q && echo) | sed -e s,\$,/, -e \$s/\$/./ '"`")
    set target = $target:q${line:h:q}
    if ( $line:q =~ */ ) set target = $target:q'\
'
end

echo $target:q

  '  "  \  `  $#  




Good show! and only one call to sed to make things work.

Actually, such fanatical work (even for csh) deserves several other upvotes.
